# How to import a stylesheet from an environment file in Neo4j Docker

Tags: css, neo4j, cypher

I'm running Neo4j on docker and would like to import the style.grass file using an environment file. Below is the context of the env file:

```
NEO4J_browser_post__connect__cmd='style node {diameter: 50px;color: #A5ABB6;border-color: #9AA1AC;border-width: 2px;text-color-internal: #FFFFFF;font-size: 10px;}'
```

The errors I get are:

```
Unknown command :font-size: 10px
Unknown command :text-color-internal: #FFFFFF
Unknown command :border-width: 2px
Unknown command :border-color: #9AA1AC
Unknown command :color: #A5ABB6
```

So Neo4j is interpreting the attributes of the stylesheet as console commands. How can I change the environment file such that all the attributes in the stylesheet are interpreted correctly, so not as console commands.
I have also tried `NEO4J_browser_post__connect__cmd='style style.grass'` but got the same errors. I can't fetch the stylesheet from an external link, so it has to be done internally.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, you *can* set `browser.post_connect_cmd` using the environment variable `NEO4J_browser_post__connect__cmd`, but that's where your luck ends.

To store information in the environment variable that is readable by Neo4j you need to remove spaces - so

```
NEO4J_browser_post__connect__cmd=style{diameter:50px}
```

will pass the `style{diameter:50px}` string to Neo4j - **BUT** the lack of spaces renders your style script uninterpretable, and the browser throws an `UnknownCommandError` -- I suspect the best solution is to host the script somewhere else, or use `neo4j.conf`.

Answer (score -1):

The startup parameter in the neo4j.conf file is "browser.post_connect_cmd", not "NEO4J_browser_post__connect__cmd".  I use this same parameter to automatically open browser guides on startup.

You could try removing the single quotes as well, and have:

```
browser.post_connect_cmd=style node {diameter: 50px;color: #A5ABB6;border-color: #9AA1AC;border-width: 2px;text-color-internal: #FFFFFF;font-size: 10px;}
```

I haven't tested it, but this should be equivalent to running the command manually:

```
:style node {
   diameter: 50px;
   color: #A5ABB6;
   border-color: #9AA1AC;
   border-width: 2px;
   text-color-internal: #FFFFFF;
   font-size: 10px;
}
```

I see similar discussions on this topic at https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-browser/issues/171

Good luck.